# Using jquery $.ajax function() to call a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax, json

I have the following code:

```
var twitterUrl = escape("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=" + username);
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "twitter.js?url=" + twitterUrl,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(d, status, req) {
        var tweets = eval('(' + d + ')');
        showTweets(tweets);
    }
});
```

I want the `twitter.js` file to get the twitterUrl variable and process it to obtain the json file generatd by the twitter API. The questions are:

1. How can I read and parse the twitterUrl in the twitter.js file?
2. How can I simulate a `stream_get_contents` PHP function in JavaScript to parse and process the twitter link and pass the result back to the original page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.

```
var twitterUrl = location.search.match(/[?&]url=(.*?)(&|$)/i);
twitterUrl = twitterUrl && twitterUrl[1];
```

2.
Where `myMethod` is the function you want to send the data to:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = twitterUrl + '&callback=myMethod';
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
head.insertBefore(script, head.firstChild);
```

So for example `myMethod`:

```
var myMethod = function(data) {
  alert('Your name is ' + data.user.name);
};
```